# Must a subset of $\mathbb{R} ^n$, that has a dimension of $1$, be formed by a union of lines?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, euclidean-geometry, dimension-theory-analysis

Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R} ^n$ with a [box-dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Bouligand_dimension) of $1$. Is $S$ necessarily a union of lines (including "curved" lines and line segments)?

If no, then is $S$ at least an infinite set of points that can be [totally disconnected](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotallyDisconnectedSpace.html), such that $S$ doesn't form a line?

Thanks

Comment: What about curved lines? For example, a circle?

Comment: @somos  yes, those count as lines too.

Comment: If so,then please update your question to include **curved** lines also, but how do you define a "curve"? You want to exclude pathological casese such as Hilbert curve.

Comment: @somos if it can help, we can ignore non-straight lines for now.

Comment: What about the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set)?

Comment: @Somos  I think you misunderstand what I mean (sorry if I was a bit unclear), so I have clarified the question.

Comment: It is not quite clear to me, what you would like to know. Clearly the set cannot have finitely many points (then the box dimension is zero). So what do you mean by "If no, then is S at least an infinite set of points [...]"?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven  Indeed, S cannot be a finite set of points.  The question is can it then be a *totally disconnected* space such that no line segment is contained in it?

Comment: Yes, it can. Take the set $\{ (q, 0, \dots, 0)\in \mathbb{R}^n \ : \ q\in [0;1]\cap \mathbb{Q}\}$ which has box dimension 1 and is totally disconnected.

Comment: [The box dimension of rational numbers is 1](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~scott/Book331/Fractal_Dimension.html)

Comment: @YuiToCheng  Thank you, this has answered my question.